# apostrophe in email name

Tags: email

I'm trying to send an invitation to someone to become a user of a private Wordpress blog, but WP apparently doesn't accept an apostrophe appearing in the name in the email address as valid. For example, it seems it would consider maryo'grady@hotmail.com as an invalid email address, because of the apostrophe in Mary's surname. Has anyone else had this problem, and is there a way around it, by substituting a different character in place of the apostrophe?

Comment: Note also that [it is valid](http://isemail.info/maryo%27grady%40hotmail.com).

Answer (score 2):

Filter `is_email` and `sanitize_email`, then apply a better check:

```
namespace Wpse\Email;

add_filter( 'is_email',       __NAMESPACE__ . '\check_mail_address', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'sanitize_email', __NAMESPACE__ . '\check_mail_address', 10, 2 );

function check_mail_address( $result, $email )
{
    return filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
}
```

The PHP function is still not RFC 5321 compliant, but better than the WordPress check.

Comment: A better check would be `return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('/@.+\./', $email);` [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php#answer-5855853)

Comment: @Bondye I wrote this _especially_ to allow me the use of my local addresses.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. Maybe rename the function to check_mail_local ;)

Comment: nice and short (I thought WordPress would never include a code with the PHP `filter_*` functions, so I was surprised to find it in one place, the `class-phpmailer.php` class  ;-)